# Series expansion using complex variables

Tags: series-expansion

Suppose I have a function

```
F[r_]:= A/r + B/r^2 + Conjugate[C]/r^3
```

with A, B, C being complex numbers and r being a real variable. I would like to series expand

```
Re[F[r]^3]
```

in powers of inverse r.  How do I tell mathematica to treat A, B, and C as complex numbers while r as a real variable? Can I do this when defining the function F[r]? Can I do this while using Series[] ? Which is the shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Letting

```
F[r_]:= A/r + B/r^2 + Conjugate[C]/r^3
```

here are two ways:

```
Series[ComplexExpand[Re[F[r]^3], {A, B, C}], {r, ∞, 4}] // FullSimplify
   (A^3 + Conjugate[A]^3)/(2 r^3) + Re[-3 Im[A] (B Im[A] + 2 A Im[B]) +
   3 B Re[A]^2]/r^4 + O[r, ∞]^5
```

if you only want a few terms, or

```
Collect[ComplexExpand[Re[F[r]^3], {A, B, C}] /. r -> 1/u, u, FullSimplify] /. u -> 1/r
```

if you want the full expansion.